# Android-Keyboard shows randomly onResume

Tags: android, android-activity, keyboard

when i navigate to another activity and get back to old activity keyboard shows. Not only this also whenever i show a alert dialog keyboard also shows after dialog dismiss.

in manifiest i use this configuartion : "adjustPan"

ı use this because my activity has a bottom navigation bar and if i dont use it bottom bar move above to keyboard and i dont want that.

I also tried "INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN" but when i use this adjustpan method is not working and bottom bar moves above keyboard.

How can i prevent keyboard to show randomly?

Answer (score 2):

If keyboard shows when you get back to your activity, you can call hide keyboard method in your onResume():

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
  View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
  //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
  if (view == null) {
      view = new View(activity);
  }
  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with this way.

I added this line to parent layout of every fragment that i don't want keyboard to show.

```
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

hope this helps somebody